# Python - Copy several files from several locations to one folder based on a excel file

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, shutil

Good day

We need to copy data from one server to another server for a migration. I have received an Excel list in which I have the following columns.

[image: Simple Example of the Strucure]

All contained files must be copied. Unfortunately, the new path where the documents should be copied should also be written into the DataFrame and finally the whole thing should be exported as CSV.

The export is no problem.

But I have problems with the loop.
In my imagination:

I have a basic destination path
 - I work per line
 - I copy the file using the file path
 - I add the "destination path + file name" in new path in the data frame
 - Repeat on the next line

So i started with:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Docdf = pd.read_excel('S:\Test_MSC.xlsx')

destpath = 'S:\\Test_dest\\'

for f in Docdf:
[...] *problem*

Docdf .to_csv("enchanced_file.csv", sep = ";", encoding = "utf-8")
```

How do I best build the loop?
Many thanks for the support

Comment: That seems like a lot of text just to ask "how do I copy a file in Python?"...

Comment: It is not only copy. It is copy and "note" the information. But sometimes - I rarely program - you just have a blockade and even 1-2h searching the internet just doesn't give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for f in Docdf:` is wrong, it will iterate over **column names**. You need to iterate over rows or just use the `apply` method:

```
from shutils import copyfile

def copying(row):
    oldpath = row[4] # column E
    newpath = destpath + row[1] # column B
    copyfile(oldpath, newpath)
    return newpath

Docdf['new_path'] = Docdf.apply(copying, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello Błotosmętek

Thank you very much for your answer. This brings me forward. If I understand the code correctly. This one just copies. If there are files with the same name, then they are just hard-copied?

For a rename I would have to include another loop?

Comment: Yes, they're just copied, and you didn't mention any need of renaming.

Comment: That's ok - just wanted to clarify. :) Thx